# How to set text in InputField in UnityEngine by code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that after my changes in code, Unity doesn't do any actions with InputField (after starting the game, I mean). I want that after setting text value for InputField, this one changes in Unity after starting. Could you help me with it?
Code looks like:

```
public class TextBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public InputField input;
    void Start()
    {
        input.text = "some text for input";
       
    }
 }
```

I tried to do this by Awake() and GameObject as well, but It was unsuccessfully (maybe It was just my mistake)
Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Code looks fine. Compare with [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html). Did you assign the public `input` variable via inspector? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @KYL3R, In inspector, when I try set Input, this one doesn't work, even when I try to set on it InputField item
(Before It, I drag my code file to InputField element, I want to believe it was right action)

Comment: @Pac0, I want to change text value InputField by C# Script. For example, after creating InputField object in Unity, I want to change text value for this object by code and see the result in Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your script (added an include) and it works with a proper setup in Unity.

1. Create **Legacy** Input Field (GameObject -> UI -> Legacy -> Input Field):

[image]

2. Then add your script and drag the Input Field *Component* to the public field. Hit play and the input text changes. as expected:

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeInputFieldText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField input;
    void Start()
    {
        input.text = "some text for input";
    }
}
```

---

**New** Input field (**TextMeshPro**):

1. Add Gameobject -> UI -> Input Field - TextMeshPro (import TMP Essentials if prompted!)

[image]

2. Add your Script and drag the TMP Input Field in the slot. This time, your script needs a variable of type `TMP_InputField` and the required Import is `using TMPro;` See below:

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ChangeInputFieldText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField input;
    void Start()
    {
        input.text = "some text for input";
    }
}
```